# How to write LDAP policy for existing/new users

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap, phpldapadmin

I have configured LDAP client and LDAP server on ubuntu 18.04 server, and I can successfully create user and groups etc on LDAP server using phpLDAPadmin, but I want to create customized policies where I can restrict the users access to some specific groups or dedicated previlages.

I have researched about writing different policies but I can only find password policy for LDAP and unanswered questions. Please advice me if theres any other LDAP server management tool or phpLDAPadmin is good enough to manage LDAP server, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See *man slapd.conf*. Off topic.

Comment: As far as restricting access to groups is concern you can use Access Control of openldap.. Go through this documentation https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html